# Show loading screen while activity is loading in background

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have an app with bottomnavigationview using which I can navigate between five different fragments/pages. When I switch over to a different page, the app waits(i.e loads the page) for 0.5 - 1 second and then displays it. I want that on moving to another page, the app shows a loading screen on the foreground while the page loads in the background, and when it's done loading the loading screen goes away and the loaded page appears? How can I do that? Making the loading screen is not a problem but implementing it in the way I want is.
My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RelativeLayout btmnavl;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
            new Home()).commit();

    LinearLayout team = findViewById(R.id.team_lay);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.btmnav);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navlistner);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
            new Live()).commit();


}
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navlistner =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.live:
                        selectedFragment = new Live();
                        hide();

                        break;

                    case R.id.home:
                        selectedFragment = new Home();
                        break;

                    case R.id.schedule:
                        selectedFragment = new Schedule();
                        break;

                    case R.id.feed:
                        selectedFragment = new Feed();
                        break;

                    case R.id.recent:
                        selectedFragment = new Recent();
                        break;

                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        selectedFragment).commit();
                return true;

            }
        };





private void hide(){
    btmnavl = findViewById(R.id.btmnavl);
    btmnavl.setVisibility(View.GONE);

 }

 }
```

Comment: Is this what you need? https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565

Comment: No, i dont want a splash screen, i want a loading screen to display over a fragment while the fragment loads in the background...ill edit my post to make it clear

Comment: When you say loading screen, you mean like a progress-bar?

Comment: Yes a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

To add a progress bar which is only visible when the page is loading, add the following to your activity XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you can fetch it with `loadingPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel);`

And set visibility with:

`loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

`loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

In your case, you can set it to `GONE` right before the `.commit()`, so:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
            new Live());
loadingPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
transaction.commit();
```

This should work for you I believe, just don't forget to set it back to `VISIBLE` when you load other fragments, and edit the above XML to fit your specific layout better.

Comment: Nope...its not working...atleast not like it should....If i dont set the visibility it to GONE then it stays and if i Set the visibility to GONE then it dosent appear at all.

Comment: Visibility should be set to `GONE` right at the start of `onCreate`. That setting means that the progress bar is "there", you just can't see it and it doesn't take space in the layout. You then need to set it to `VISIBLE` and back to `GONE` interchangeably, following the general pattern of  `VISIBLE` -> `[loading things]` -> `GONE`, rinse and repeat for every chunk of code where you need to load things for any amount of time.